# asp.net windows authentication caches username of first person to navigate to website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I'm having a strange issue where HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name seems to be caching the first user who hits the website after refreshing IIS. The site is a .NET MVC 4 application. I verified this behavior by printing the value of HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name on the landing page and having several people in the office go to the page (it always shows name of user who first navigates to page). I verified in IIS settings that windows authentication is turned on and anonymous authentication is turned off.

I tried googling for a solution to this for sometime and haven't found anything though one person online had something similar and found they had a flag associated with "caching" turned on in their config file but I dont seem to have anything like that in my config file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should use `Controller.User` to access the info, and also make sure load balancers such as F5 do not cache user sessions.

Comment: Please show your for displaying the value

Comment: what version of IIS are you issuing ? Check if kernel caching is enbled https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731903(v=ws.10).aspx and disable it.

Comment: @LexLi Big thank you Lex! I believe this actually fixed my issue

Comment: Though I would still be interested to hear why using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in a .NET MVC4 application in an auxiliary class always retrieves my credentials regardless of whose computer or who's signed into the computer. But glad I found a solution/work-around (via @LexLi).